# Want to display font awesome when hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have navigation. I want to display icon when hover on a particular `a` tag.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="linked">
            All  <i class="fa fa-align-justify justify"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="linked">
            DEVELOPMENT <i class="fa fa-align-justify justify"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="linked">
            BRANDING <i class="fa fa-align-justify justify"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="linked">
            DESIGN <i class="fa fa-align-justify justify"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="linked">
            PRINT <i class="fa fa-align-justify justify"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
.justify{
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$('.linked').hover(function(){
    $('.justify').show("slow");
},function(){
    $(".justify").hide("slow");
});
```

I know my JS is wrong because when you hover on any `a` it will show the icon on all other `a` also. I don't know how to use 'this' in JS. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` to find the element within the one which triggered the event:

```
$('.linked').hover(function(){
    $('.justify', this).show("slow");
},function(){
    $(".justify", this).hide("slow");
});
```

Or alternatively you can use a single `hover` handler and `toggle`:

```
$('.linked').hover(function(){
    $('.justify', this).toggle("slow");
});
```